# Is there an invert_transform method available for sklearn.Normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have a dataframe df defined as follows :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': np.random.randint(-100, 100, 1000).astype(float)})
```

and I used sklearn.preprocessing method Normalization as follows :

```
scaler = preprocessing.Normalizer()
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_df, columns=df.columns)
```

Now I would like to get the original values from scaled_df. I went through the documentation and could not find invert_transform method like we have for

```
 preprocessing.MinMaxScaler  
 preprocessing.RobustScaler
```

Am I missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The transform implemented by `Normalizer` has no inverse. There is no `inverse_transform` method because such a method would have to pull information about the original norm of each vector from thin air.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more when you say thin air.